# How to toggle instead of Show

Tags: jquery, toggle

As per the below code, I have tried to toggle a element. On similar note, when I click that element it should appear and again if I click that element it should disappear. Currently, when I click that element it appears but it is not disappearing on clicking again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('ul.nav-tabs li a').removeClass('active');
        $('ul.nav-tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
        $('.tab-content #146f632b316a42b48488b8c1da12678a, .tab-content #146f632b316a42b48488b8c1da12678a .row').show();
        $('ul.main-navigation li a').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-href');



            $('.mega-navigation .row').hide();
            $('.mega-navigation, .btnHide').show();
            //$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
            $('ul.main-navigation li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            //$(tab_id).addClass('current');
            $(tab_id).show();
            if(tab_id == '#tab2c8d0d2ec797404b9b1b646e797c98de'){
                //alert('if');
                $('ul.nav-tabs li a').removeClass('active');
                $('ul.nav-tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #146f632b316a42b48488b8c1da12678a, .tab-content #146f632b316a42b48488b8c1da12678a .row').show();
            }
        })

        $('.btnHide').click(function(){
            $('ul.main-navigation li a').removeClass('active');
            $('.mega-navigation .row, .btnHide').hide();
        })


        $('ul.nav-tabs li a').click(function(){
            var in_tab_id = $(this).attr('data-href');

            $('ul.nav-tabs li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            $('.tab-content .tab-pane .row').hide();
            $('.tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active');

            $(in_tab_id).addClass('active');
            $(in_tab_id+','+in_tab_id+' .row').show();

        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           try this
          $('.mega-navigation .row').toggle(showOrHide );

             if ( showOrHide === true ) {
            $( '.mega-navigation .row' ).show();
            } else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
            $( '.mega-navigation .row' ).hide();
            }
```

DOes That Help?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your html too.. but anyway try this, instead of using .hide() or .show()... Use this .toggle() for both. You can also actually put a timer. eg .toggle(400)